# Can specific programs or software be ascertained from the hardware?

Tags: software-engineering

I having been thinking about software and hardware and their relationship. I am a layman and do not have specialized knowledge on the subject. I wondered whether if studying a particular hardware a scientist could find out what software or programs are within the computer and if possible could I be given resources to read more about such similar subject matter. Thanks!!

Comment: When you talk about studying hardware do you mean a particular instance of hardware, say, your phone for example, or the design of the hardware, as in all the information needed to create a new instance?

Comment: Back in the day when ["single chip microcomputers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_chip_microcontroller) where produced with "mask ROM", it wasn't that hard to "read out" the program. (The programmable variants more often than not allowed program read-out after programming for verification - and pulling the plug on read-out to impede plagiarism and [reverse engineering](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering).)